# rails rake task paused for a while and resumed pressing enter on console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-prompt, rake-task, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I experienced weird issue today, I was running rake task witch does some batch processing  one after the other.

One the console I log progress details on command prompt.

In the rake task I make API calls to salesforce in loop.

It run continuously for about 5 minutes and then it paused I did not notice as cmd was minimized.

When I checked cmd for progress it was paused for 10+ minutes. By mistakenly I just pressed **Enter key** on console and it **resumed**!!!

Please find screen shot of cmd.[image]

What caused rake task to pause? is it code or console ?

**EDIT**:
Environment Windows 64 bit and Rails 5.1 and Ruby 2.3.3

Comment: unless the script is waiting for an input from the console I don't think it was paused, did you check what endpoint it was hitting when paused, it could just be long response time

Comment: no where in code process waits for an input. If its long response how it get started as soon as I hit enter and it happened to me more than once.